# Hot to suppress a BadExitStatusException error from a jenkins pipeline after an ansible playbook run

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I have a Jenkins pipeline that runs an ansible playbook against a few servers

```
node {
stage('Get Playbook') {
    dir('ansible-dir') {
       git branch: 'master',
       credentialsId: 'creds',
       url: 'ssh://git@gitserver.com'
    }
}

withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: 'ansible', usernameVariable: 'username', passwordVariable: 'password']]){

    def remote = [:]
    remote.name = 'Remote Ansible Server'
    remote.host = 'server.domain.com'
    remote.user = username
    remote.password = password
    remote.allowAnyHosts = true

    stage('Copy dir to remote server'){
        sshPut remote: remote, from: '/localdir', into: '/home/remote/jenkins'
    }

stage('Run ansible playbook'){
        sshCommand remote: remote, command: 'ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/home/remote/jenkins/ansible.cfg ansible-playbook /home/remote/jenkins/playbook.yml -vvv'
    }

    stage('Copy report to local machine') {
        sshGet remote: remote, from: '/home/remote/jenkins/reports', into: '/home/user/reports', override: true
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is the 'Copy report to local machine' stage doesn't always run. Occasionally a server will fail in the play recap, which isn't a problem in itself as the report generated in the playbook accounts for that and has logging to identify it.

The problem being that when a server does fail in the play recap, jenkins give the following error.

```
org.hidetake.groovy.ssh.session.BadExitStatusException: Command returned exit status 2: ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/home/remote/jenkins/ansible.cfg ansible-playbook /home/remote/jenkins/playbook.yml -vvv
```

This prevents the next stage in the pipeline from running. Is there a way to suppress this error output so the pipeline continues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out by putting the stage running the playbook in a try catch

```
try {
    stage('Copy dir to remote server'){
    sshPut remote: remote, from: '/localdir', into: '/home/remote/jenkins'
} catch(e) {
    build_ok = false
    echo e.toString()
}
```

This lets it continue and to the next stage.